# xamarin application not quitting right

Tags: windows, xamarin, mono, gtk#

I noticed something strange with my Xamarin application.

First in Xamarin: Running the Application was fine until I click the upper right X to close the App. In Xamarin the button on the left is still a red square and I can "stop the current startup project".

Second: after packing up the application (7zip) and starting it out of the archive, after closing the app, 7zip told me to stop the application before it is able to close the archive.

Is there anything i'm missing here? Do i have to setup anything to shutdown the App properly?

there even is a OnDeleteEvent

```
protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit();
    a.RetVal = true;
}
```

but with a breakpoint there, it seems not to be used when clicking the X-Button.

Note: I'm using the GTK#2.0 Project template with Xamarin 6.2

Answer (score 0):

i had to add the line

```
this.DeleteEvent += new global::Gtk.DeleteEventHandler(this.OnDeleteEvent);
```

into the sourcecode of my MainWindow. Somehow this line was missing.
It's working as intended now.